# automatically expand the result of an odata function

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, odata

I defined an odata function to mimic $search which is not supported yet in the recent core release. I want to return the core entity plus an expanded entity which would translate into a js object on each Person in the returned json values array.

I tried `odata/People/MyNS.Find(text='john', orderby='CreatedOn')?$expand=CurrentWork` where CurrentWork is on People, but that did not work.

Thoughts on how to do this?

```
  // my controller code for the function
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult<ICollection<People>> Find([FromODataUri] string text,
        [FromODataUri] string orderBy)
        {
            if (text == null || text.Length == 0)
                return Get().ToList();
            if (orderBy == null || orderBy.Length == 0)
                orderBy = "CreatedOn";
            return _db.People
                .Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(text)
                    || p.LastName.Contains(text)
                    || p.Nickname.Contains(text))
                .OrderBy(orderBy)
                .Take(5000)
                .ToList();
        }
```

Regular expansion of CurrentWork in a non-function works fine e.g. `odata/People?$expand=CurrentWork`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the Linq query, it's fetching only People data and not any of it's child collections. You should use `Include` to fetch data for child collections along with parent entity like below. Read more on loading related entities [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

```
// my controller code for the function
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<ICollection<People>> Find([FromODataUri] string text,
    [FromODataUri] string orderBy)
{
    if (text == null || text.Length == 0)
        return Get().ToList();
    if (orderBy == null || orderBy.Length == 0)
        orderBy = "CreatedOn";
    return _db.People
        .Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(text)
            || p.LastName.Contains(text)
            || p.Nickname.Contains(text))
        .Include(p => p.CurrentWork) // I have added this line
        .OrderBy(orderBy)
        .Take(5000)
        .ToList();
}
```

Note: You still need to use $expand=CurrentWork as query string. Without this query string, server will remove child collections before sending response to client.

Comment: That does seem to do it. After reading more of the documentation I also decided to let aspnetcore invoke the query by returning an IOrderedQueryable, setting maxtop on the controller, drop tracking and use regexs which forces evaluation on the client side after the initial fetch but allows me to use wildcards easier. Not great for large people datasets but works well enough. My "includes" still pull in too much data but that's a concern for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with in the end. I noticed that the included entities were pulling in alot of data from the database so I reduced down the pull quite a bit by being specific. Include just pulled everything and I could not reduce the `Include` down directly so I had to use a `Select`.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IOrderedQueryable Find2([FromODataUri] string text,
    [FromODataUri] string orderBy)
    {
        if (orderBy == null || orderBy.Length == 0)
            orderBy = "CreatedOn DESC";
        if (text == null || text.Length == 0)
            return Get().OrderBy(orderBy);
        var r = LikeToRegular(text);
        return _db.People
        .AsNoTracking() // can't use if using lazy loading
        .Select(p => new
        {
            p.FirstName,
            p.LastName,
            p.Nickname,
            p.CreatedOn,
            p.CurrentWork.Title,
            p.CurrentWork.Company.CompanyName
        })
        // Forces local computation, so pulls entire people dataset :-(
        .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.LastName ?? "", r)
        || Regex.IsMatch(x.FirstName ?? "", r, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        || Regex.IsMatch(x.Nickname ?? "", r, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        || Regex.IsMatch($"{x.FirstName} {x.LastName}", r,
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        .OrderBy(orderBy);
    }
    // Allow some wildcards in the search...
    public static String LikeToRegular(String value)
    {
        return "^" + Regex.Escape(value)
        .Replace("_", ".")
        .Replace("%", ".*") + "$";
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, it seems that depending on how you declare the function you may or may not get back a valid odata response even though you will not get an error. The function above returns a pure json array as the response that is not valid odata. Vinit's comment does seem to be correct that you need to include the $expand query parameter in order for the `Include` to not only pull the data from the database but also include it in an odata formatted response if you are producing a valid odata response to begin with.